# C++ nullptrt_t as argument in a constructor

Tags: c++11, nullptr

Reading some code I found a class accepting just the new C++11 `nullptr_t` as parameter. The class looks like the one below.

Am I correct that the only thing I can construct an object by using exclusively `nullptr`?

```
class CA {
 public:
 CA(nullptr_t) {}  
};
```

Comment: Yes. See e.g. [this `std::nullptr_t` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t).

Comment: Now I'm wondering if `std::nullpr_t()` is a valid expression. Can't see why not, so that would be another option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Am I correct that the only thing I can construct an object by using exclusively nullptr?*

No. This is covered in §4.10 [conv.ptr]:

> A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

where a *null pointer constant* is defined as follows:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

In other words, your constructor can be invoked also with various integer literals of value 0:

```
CA{ 0 };
CA{ 0u };
CA{ 0LL };
CA{ 0x0 };
```

Answer (score 6):

The standard specifies, at §2.14.7.1, that:

> The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [ Note: `std::nullptr_t` is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value. —endnote]

The only prvalue of type `nullptr_t` is `nullptr` which is then convertible to other pointer type following the rules specified in §4.10 and §4.11.

Other integer literals can be converted to a value of type `std::nullptr_t` as per §4.10.1:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Therefore you can use an interger literal with value zero or `nullptr`.

Specifically:

- `0`
- `0u`, `0U`
- `0l`, `0L`
- `0ul`, `0uL`, `0Ul`, `0UL`
- `0ll`, `0LL`
- `0ull`, `0uLL`, `0ULL`
- `nullptr`
- `NULL`

I might be missing some cases, so fell free to correct me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

> std::nullptr_t is the type of the null pointer literal, nullptr.

Which means yes, you can construct this object only with *nullptr* or a corresponding integral value (as in the answer below explained).
Check out [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) example as it shows a situation where u need it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yes it is true and that include also usage of value '0' for the null pointer and 'NULL' (credit to PIOTR S. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-s  who deleted its response..don't know why).

Comment: in C++11 NULL is still (void*)0 for retro compatibility. That's why the new literal nullptr had to be introduced.

Comment: @dau_sama: No, and that was never the case. In every C++ standard, `NULL` has had an integral type. Could be `0`, could be `0L`, could be quite a few other things in theory, but `(void*)0` is not an integral type.